# How do I create a content type that has another content type embedded inside of it?

Tags: nodes, entities

I'm building a content type for a journal-type product. In each journal there are a number journal articles that vary from journal to journal, which have their own unique fields (like author, date, subject, synopsis, etc). Right now I've set it up so you fill out all of the contents for the articles and then you pull them into the journal via entity reference.

Ideally though, it would be great if I could just streamline all of this into the same "create content" form. For example, when I click "create new journal", I want to get all the fields for my journal plus the ability to dynamically add journal articles and all of their fields.  It could be in a different tab or something, it just needs to be in the same create journal content type form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) useful.

> Provides a widget for inline management (creation, modification,
>   removal) of referenced entities. The primary use case is the parent ->
>   children one (product display -> products, order -> line items, etc.),
>   where the child entities are never managed outside the parent form.
>   Existing entities can also be referenced.

Answer (score 1):

Use [References dialog](https://www.drupal.org/project/references_dialog). "This module extends reference fields like the user and node reference fields by adding links to add, edit and search for references through a dialog"

Answer (score 0):

I think this module can help you: https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews
If you embed the view in a block on the path node/add/journal

Comment: I don't think editable views is fitted for this use case, References Dialog is...

Comment: Agreed, I've up-voted your answer :)

Comment: But glad you pointed it out Coleman - i have long been a watcher of https://www.drupal.org/project/editablefields having used it in D6 for getting editable fields in a View - looks like this new kid on the block does that and more.